# Adding another picker to UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am trying to create a UISlider that has two pickers.I already have a **UISlider** which is working and functioning correctly.

Is there a way where I can add a picker to the **UISlider** that I already have or do I need to scrap everything that I have and programatically code it so that it has two pickers?

I would like the slider to have a minimum picker and a maximum picker. Im not sure if it is possible to add another picker to the slider i already have.

Here is the code i have for my current uislider.

```
- (IBAction)slider:(id)sender {

    UISlider *slide = (UISlider *)sender;

    CGFloat value = slide.value;
    NSUInteger index = value * (priceDelegate.values.count - 1);
    NSString *priceString =  priceDelegate.values[index];

    [self.tf_price setText:priceString];
    _appDelegate.int_minPriceV = index;

}
```

If some one could help me I would be really grateful, thank you.

Comment: be a bit more descriptive. what do you mean when you say "add a picker to the UISlider"

Comment: @staticVoidMan sorry, i don't know what is called so its really difficult to explain. what i mean is i would like to have a maximum and minimum on one ulslider that i have already created so you can scroll the max to what ever price and the min to what ever price they require.

Comment: picker as in the knob? so... you want 2 knobs on a single UISlider to, kinda, define a range of acceptable values? like $50 to $100 or something like that?

Answer (score 4):

If it's a range slider you want then you're out of luck with the standard UISlider as it does not provide this kind of functionality.
You can subclass UISlider and do your own thing but we can all agree that that's somewhat a tedious job.

You can try these instead:
link1: https://github.com/muZZkat/NMRangeSlider

link2A: https://github.com/buildmobile/iosrangeslider
OR...
link2B: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rangeslider

---

If you're feeling a bit adventurous then follow this tutorial:
http://www.sitepoint.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one/

Comment: I found here a `Swift` implementation for `range slider` with source code and example project: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift